# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in a Virtual Device

Tags: android

I recently changed computers and so had to reinstall the ADT.  Since then Ive been getting this error, in a virtual device.

Logcat:

```
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000): Could not send email
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000): javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):   nested exception is:
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/csvname.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:676)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at com.example.blueharvest.Mail.send(Mail.java:125)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at com.example.blueharvest.ChargeActivity$6.onClick(ChargeActivity.java:213)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/csvname.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:110)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:318)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:874)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:444)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:102)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:897)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:330)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1745)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:636)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    ... 15 more
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
04-13 07:50:00.232: E/MailApp(2000):    ... 27 more
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Code:

```
public void exportDb(Context context) {

    SQLiteDatabase _db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "");
    File exportDir = getDir(context);

    if (!exportDir.exists())
    {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(exportDir, "csvname.csv");
    try
    {
        file.createNewFile();               
        CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM chrgData",null);
        csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
        while(curCSV.moveToNext())
        {
           //Which column you want to export
            String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2), curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4)};
            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
        }
        csvWrite.close();
        curCSV.close();
    }
    catch(Exception sqlEx)
    {
        Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }
    _db.close();
}

public File getDir(Context context) {
    File exportDir;
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        exportDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"");
    } else {
        exportDir = context.getCacheDir();
    }                
    return exportDir;
}
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated, and please let me know if any other information is needed.

Thanks in advance,

Brad.

Comment: Brad, please check whether your virtual device has an SDCard support property set. I'm not sure but this could be the cause.

Comment: Depending on the version of Android you're targeting, you may need to also add `<uses-permission android:name=android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE />` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: @FireAndIce & Squonk - Thanks so much for the quick reply.  So it turns out it was the virtual device.  I had actually tried recreating the virtual device earlier, but just recreated it again and this time changed the size.  Now its working again :) .  Ive also added the read permissions on external storage, just in case.  Thanks again so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the error was caused due to an issue with the virtual device.  Removed and recreated the device and the error was no more.

Comment: I had the same exact problem.  I re-created my virtual device with SD card memory, I didn't have any SD card memory in my first device.